# Prove that $\sum_{u = 1}^{N} \sum_{v=1}^{N} \left(\left[\sqrt{u^2-4v} \in Z\right]+\left[\sqrt{u^2+4v} \in Z\right]\right) = D \left(N\right)-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum, pell-type-equations

For a given height $N$.  I am performing various sums involved in the counting of the number of monic quadratics, cubics, etc. that factor over a range.   I noticed by experiment that the above sum over the number of quadratic discriminates that are perfect squares is equal to the sum of the number of divisors minus 1 or $D \left(N\right) - 1$.  The original form was $$\sum_{u = 1}^{N} \sum_{v=1}^{N} \left[\sqrt{u^2-4v} \in Z\right]+ \sum_{u = 1}^{N} \sum_{v=-N}^{-1}\left[\sqrt{u^2-4v} \in Z\right] = D \left(N\right)-1.$$  The case when $v=0$ has been factored out as $N$.

I have not seen any similar expressions in the literature.  I am looking for a proof of this or suggestions.

Further numerical tests for a given $u$ has shown that the inner sum is the number of divisors of $u$ with a modification at the last value or

$$\sum_{v=1}^{N} \left(\left[\sqrt{u^2-4v} \in Z\right] + \left[\sqrt{u^2+4v} \in Z\right]\right) =
\begin{cases}
\tau \left(u\right), & u < N, \\
\tau \left(u\right) - 1, & u = N
\end{cases}$$

where $\tau \left(u\right)$ is the number of divisors.  A table of the inner sum for the values of $u=20$ as v varies from 1 to 20 is shown below

$$\begin{matrix}
v & S & [u^2-4v \in Z] & [u^2+4v \in Z] & \tau \left(v\right) \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
5 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
6 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
7 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
8 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
9 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
10 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
11 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
12 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\
13 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
14 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
15 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
16 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 5 \\
17 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
18 & 6 & 3 & 3 & 6 \\
19 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & {5}^{*} & {2}^{*} & 3 & 6 \\
\end{matrix}$$

where $S$ is the sum of the two inversion brackets along with the two partial inversion bracket sums with the last column being the number of divisors which shows the -1 correction.  If the inner sum result is proved then the final sum follows.

The series for $\left[\sqrt{u^2-4v} \in Z\right]$ is identified as A038548 of the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequence except for the last entry as described above which is also noted to be $\left\lceil{\tau \left(u\right)}\right/2\rceil$  and the series for $\left[\sqrt{u^2+4v} \in Z\right]$ is identified as A056924 which is also noted to be $\left\lfloor{\tau \left(u\right)}\right/2\rfloor$.  No proofs are noted.

This problem looks to be counting the solutions of Pell like equations:  Count the number of solutions of $u^2-n^2=\pm 4v$ within the constraints of $u$ and $v$.